# Converting misspelled text to integer in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am totally new to Common Lisp and Lisp in general. I have a task to write using Common Lisp and can't even figure out how to begin. My program will take numbers in string format from 1 to 9, they will have one char misspelled, but the correct length; e.g.:

```
too -> 2
threa -> 3
```

and so on. I need to print the integer when given the wrong text and I seriously have no idea how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good introductory book with free PDF download: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: I will look into the book later on. Thanks for the reccommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like fun :-)

Let us do it the usual Lisp way - by *growing* the language to solve the problem.

The problem is: match a string with a dictionary so that at most one misspelling is permitted.

Here is the dictionary:

```
(defparameter *dictionary*
  (loop for i from 1 to 9 collect (cons (format nil "~R" i) i)))
```

What would it mean for two strings to match?

```
(defun diff (s1 s2)
  "Count the number of differences in the shortest common start."
  (loop for c1 across s1
    for c2 across s2
    sum (if (char= c1 c2) 0 1)))
(diff "abc" "abcde")
==> 0
(diff "abc" "aba")
==> 1
```

Now the matching:

```
(defun matchp (s1 s2)
  "Two strings match iff they have the same length and 1 different character."
  (and (= (length s1)
          (length s2))
       (= 1 (diff s1 s2))))
(matchp "a" "b")
==> T
(matchp "too" "two")
==> T
(matchp "one" "one")
==> NIL
```

Finally, find the string in the dictionary:

```
(defun parse-string (s)
  (loop for (name . number) in *dictionary*
    if (matchp name s) return number))
(parse-string "one")
==> NIL  ; not found
(parse-string "onn")
==> 1
(parse-string "too")
==> 2
(parse-string "thre3")
==> 3
(parse-string "foor")
==> 4
(parse-string "fivv")
==> 5
(parse-string "sis")
==> 6
(parse-string "sever")
==> 7
(parse-string "aight")
==> 8
(parse-string "nane")
==> 9
```

PS. I used the fairly advanced [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm) facility on purpose: if this is homework, you are probably not allowed to use it, so you will have to rewrite my code using simpler idioms.

PPS. You should probably read a book, both [acl](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html) and [pcl](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) are good.

Comment: @plank223 I don't gen any error. What error are you getting?

Comment: THANK you all so much. This saved me. Thank you a lot sds and Sylwester, turned out the problem wasn't with the code, it was another issue, thanks still.